# Sharing forms authentication between a Web Site and a Web Application

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, blogengine.net

Previously, I have implemented two separate ASP.NET Web Applications, one as a virtual application in a subfolder of the other, which successfully shared forms authentication as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx

(basically, setting up identical `<forms>` sections in the Web.config, and keys in the `<machineKey>` section)

Now, I am trying to do something similar to get [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) (which is a Web Site, not a Web Application) to work sharing forms authentication with a Web Application of mine. I have tried both putting it as a virtual application in a subfolder, and setting it up as a separate IIS site (same domain name, different port number), but I can't get the authentication to work at all: when I go to the blog while logged in to my Web Application, `Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always still "false".

I'm really not sure how to even start debugging this, since the forms authentication is handled before any of my code runs.

`<authentication>` section of the two Web.configs are the same:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms path="/" domain="localhost" timeout="129600" name=".WebSiteName"
protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" loginUrl="/admin/login.aspx"
cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

And `<machineKey>` also:

```
<machineKey validationKey="DD45C42ACEAF1E208E9B78288177EBF9C8C7C54C6D05BA2FBA90B5348B8F6987216CB098056891CFE81DC33E37C5F9A2BF1845DBF902C6E4BBFEC2341FFA3635"
decryptionKey="0C69852D8BE0948D545C35B932D394102802FAF7FA46E99B4E5B5E12546E4620"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should check or try?

Comment: Never did get this working in its original state. What I ended up doing was changing both apps - each of which had their own custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider, for no great reason - to use the standard AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and AspNetSqlRoleProvider. From that point, the shared authentication state worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a good resource for this issue: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cliffgreen/reporting-services-single-sign-on-sso-authentication-part-1)

Note there are links within this article that are useful to read.

Comment: That is unfortunate, it was a good resource.  The post has been updated.